# While number can be checked for primality in O(n^0.5) then why was it considered to be not in P until AKS test?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, p-vs-np, primes

While a basic algorithm to check for primality of a number 'n' [checking if a divides n for all a less than n] would take O(n), AKS test was the breakthrough after which it was placed in P complexity class.

Comment: Can you give a reference or proof for `[primality test] considered to be not in P`?

Answer (score 4):

The bit length of $n$ is $\log(n)$, if we forget about the most significant digits, which is always $1$ except for $n=0$. As a function of $t=\log(n)$ you have $n^{1/2}=2^{t/2}$. It is in terms of the bit length of $n$ that AKS runs in polynomial time, while the naive test doesn't.

Comment: (While $O(n)$ looks as true as $\in\mathbb P$, can you quote (and argue) a tighter bound?)

Comment: @greybeard I didn't understand your question.

Comment: What a lot of people seem to miss is that P and NP are defined in terms of Turing machines. A problem is in P if the TM takes at most a polynomial number of steps $p(n)$ where $n$ is the number of symbols on the input tape.

Comment: @Pseudonym They had a different problem, which is how $n$ is input. If $n$ is input in unary in the Turing machine, then the naive algorithm would be polynomial.